# Associating a string variable with a numeric variable

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, formatting, assignment

There is a translation operation from a numeric variable to a string variable:
`a[i_, j_] := Symbol["a" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j]]`

How could the reverse operation be done? Something like that:
`Symbol["a" <> ToString[i_] <> ToString[j_]] := a[i, j]`

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: I am getting a headache just trying to understand what you are trying to do :)  Are you trying to convert `a12` to `a[1,2]` for example?  can you give an explicit example of an input and what the output should be?

Comment: Anyways, `ReleaseHold[With[{symbol = Symbol["a" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j]]},HoldForm[symbol = a[i, j]]] ]` might work.

Comment: @Nasser, I have many string variables, I want to somehow automate data entry for them. But how can I distinguish them from each other in order to apply a loop to them?

Comment: That is why I asked for an _explicit_ example.  I am still not sure what you want. The function `ToExpression`  converts a string to its Mathematica expression. But I do not know if that is what you mean. Again, a simple example of input/output will help. It looks like Henrik was able to understand what you mean hopefully, but I still do not understand. May be because I did not have coeffe yet.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher, thanks! Why if I put this expression into the `Table` (`Table[ReleaseHold[
  With[{symbol = Symbol["a" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j]]}, 
   HoldForm[symbol = a[i, j]]]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}]`) indexes in this part `HoldForm[symbol = a[i, j]]` are colored red.

Comment: I've read all of your recent questions but I'm also confused. I have a strong feeling that you're asking [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/284701) repeatedly. What on earth are you trying to design?

Comment: @xzczd, thanks for the comment! I'll try to correct the question more clearly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with all the others, I do not understand what are you after. However, in the past, I met a comparable problem myself, where I had a good reason to do something like this. Of course, without a clear understanding of your aim, I can give a useless solution. Anyway, let us try.

You defined the function which acts only on tensors with the head `a` transforming them into a string and then into a symbol:

```
a[i_, j_] := Symbol["a" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j]]
```

Let us check

```
a[i, j] // FullForm
a[i, j] // Head
```

returns aij and Symbol correspondingly. That's OK.

Let us introduce the function

```
toTensor[expr_Symbol] := 
 Module[{x, y, z}, 
  ToExpression@Characters[ToString[expr]] /. {x_, y_, z_} :> x[y, z]]
```

Now let us apply it to `aij`:

```
Clear[a];
toTensor[aij]

(* a[i, j] *)
```

The key point here is to first apply `Clear[a]`. It is because you have already previously defined `a[i,j]` such that it immediately transforms into `aij`. Therefore, without clearing it will always return `aij`. The symbol with a different first letter you can transform without clearing

```
toTensor[bij]

(* b[i, j]  *)
```

Hope this helps.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: Simpler: `ToExpression@Characters[ToString[expr]] /. {x__} :> (First@{x})[Sequence @@ Rest@{x}]`

Answer (score 3):

I feel like we're going in circles. Over the last 2 days you've asked several questions about associating atomic symbols with headed expressions in some fashion. I'm almost certain that you don't need to do any of this. But I can't help you figure out what to do instead without knowing what problem you're actually trying to solve. And I don't mean the ultimate problem, like whatever advanced math or physics problems you're dealing with. I just mean the computational problem you're struggling with. Can you give an example that shows a bit more of the problem than you've shown us so far?

In the meantime, I'll take a stab in the dark...

Maybe want you want is to use a *data structure* rather than individual atomic values. You keep mentioning loops, so instead of things like `a[1,2]` <--> `a12`, maybe you use `Part` instead: `a[[1,2]]`. So, you can do things like this:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
a[[1, 2]]
(* 2 *)
```

Or loops:

```
Do[
  Do[
    Print[a[[i, j]]],
    {j, 2}],
  {i, 2}]
```

Or maps:

```
Map[f, a, {2}]
(* {{f[1], f[2]}, {f[3], f[4]}} *)
```

Or threading, or matrix operations, or etc etc.